# How to understand this unhandled promise rejection error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

According to the [Description section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#description) of `async function` declaration in MDN:

> ```js
> async function foo() {
>   const result1 = await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve("1")));
>   const result2 = await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve("2")));
> }
> foo();
> ```
>
> Note how the promise chain is not built-up in one go. Instead, the promise chain is constructed in stages as control is successively yielded from and returned to the async function. As a result, we must be mindful of error handling behavior when dealing with concurrent asynchronous operations.
>
> For example, in the following code an unhandled promise rejection error will be thrown, even if a `.catch` handler has been configured further along the promise chain. This is because `p2` will not be "wired into" the promise chain until control returns from `p1`.
>
> ```js
> async function foo() {
>   const p1 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve("1"), 1000));
>   const p2 = new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject("2"), 500));
>   const results = [await p1, await p2]; // Do not do this! Use Promise.all or Promise.allSettled instead.
> }
> foo().catch(() => {}); // Attempt to swallow all errors...
> ```

I don’t understand why an unhandled promise rejection error will be thrown in the second `foo` function. As far as I understand, `await p1` unwraps `p1` so evaluates to `'1'`, then `await p2` unwraps `p2` so throws `'2'`, then `foo` catches `'2'`, wraps `'2'` into a rejected promise with the value `'2'` and returns that promise, then `catch(() => {})` is called on it so `'2'` should be caught. But this is not the case, instead an unhandled promise rejection error is thrown:

```
Promise {
  <pending>,
  [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 2132,
  [Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol)]: 2126
}
> Uncaught '2'
> (node:32336) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 21)
```

Comment: Because when `p2` rejects, nothing is yet awaiting p2 and thus it just rejects on its own with no `.then()` or `.catch()` handler present.  The `await p1` will happen and will wait for `p1` to resolve BEFORE the `await p2` executes.  So, when `p2` rejects, nothing is watching that rejection yet.  It's a matter of when something is put in place to catch the `p2` rejection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to play with it myself to understand it.

The Problem is **not** `await`ing a `Promise` and just letting the exception bubble up, that is fine. The actual Problem with this code is the timeout. Or rather, the specific times the Promises resolve.

Notice that `p2` rejects **before** `p1` resolves:

```
const p1 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve("1"), 1000));
const p2 = new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject("2"), 500));
```

and that we `await p1` **before** we `await p2`:

```
const results = [
            await p1,
            await p2
];
```

This means, the moment `p2` rejects we are *not yet* awaiting `p2`, so there is *no `then` nor `catch` handler* registered for p2 *yet*. Thats why its *unhandled*.

Comment: But then how do you explain that `(async () => { const p = Promise.reject('2'); await p; })().catch(() => {})` does not raise an uncaught exception whereas the promise is rejected before being awaited?

Comment: @Maggyero - That code in your comment doesn't go back to the event loop before it is awaited.  Everything is synchronous up to the `await`.  The unhandled rejection detection happens in the event loop.

Comment: @jfriend00 Doesn’t `(async () => { const p = Promise.reject('2'); await Promise.resolve('1'); await p; })().catch(() => {})` go back to the event loop in the first `await`? Yet it does not raise an uncaught exception.

Comment: @Maggyero - Not quite back to the main event loop.  It gets back to the Promise job queue, but that is processed before the main event loop.  Perhaps you're just trying to understand all this, but it's better to just not ever leave a naked promise hanging around across an `await` or a `.then()` or across any other asynchronous operation - period.  If you do that, you'll be safe and you won't have to understand these minute details.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the explanation. Yes I’m trying to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of this problem is([[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#control_flow_effects_of_await)):

> When an await is encountered in code (either in an async function or in a module), the awaited expression is executed, while all code that depends on the expression's value is paused and pushed into the microtask queue.

So the flow of code

```
async function foo() {
    const p1 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve("1"), 1000));
    const p2 = new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject("2"), 500));
    await p1;
    await p2;
    return undefined;    // function without `return` will return undefined by default
}
foo().catch(() => {});
```

is:

1. `foo` is called
2. construct `Promise` `p1`. Since `Promise` is always constructed synchronously([[2]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise#description)), the `setTimeout` is executed and push its callback into timers queue
3. same for `p2`
4. eval `p1`, which is a `Promise` so `await` will pack all the code next as the next `then` of `p1`
5. `await` yield the control back, return this `p1.then(<all the code next>)` back, as the result of `foo()`
6. the script continue with `.catch`, so the whole chain now is like `p1.then(<all the code next>).catch(()=>{})`. **Pay attention here**, the `<all the code next>` is not our `p2`, is a function whose body has `await p2` in it, and the function is not yet execute, so `p2` itself is not in this chain yet!
7. after 500ms, `p2` is rejected. Since no `catch` is chained after `p2` itself, the toplevel will catch it and we will get the `PromiseRejectionHandledWarning`

Let's say if we interchange the timeout, the flow will be:

7. after 500ms, `p1` is resolved, its `.then(<all the code next>)` will be executed. Since the `<all the code next>` include an `await`, similar things in 4. and 5. happenes again, and the chain become something like `p1.then(()=>p2).then(<all the code next the 2nd await>).catch(()=>{})`, and we know if a function inside `then` return a `Promise`, that `Promise` is got into the chain([[3]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#chaining)), so now we have a `catch` after `p2`
8. after 1000ms, `p2` is rejected and catched

To conclude, let's rewrite the original code with pure `Promise` only, without `async` and `await`:

```
function foo() {
    const p1 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve("1"), 1000));
    const p2 = new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject("2"), 500));
    return p1.then(() => p2).then(() => undefined);
}
foo().catch(() => {});
```